# Html inner table error

Tags: html

Below is my html code consists of a table with two rows and the second row consists of two tables in each td. now the second table in the second td displays in middle but not in top. I want that table in top

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Upload a File to BlockChain</th>
    <th>Transaction Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 100%" bgcolor="#cceeff">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name <br> <input type=text name=textnames
                        placeholder="Employee Name" id="textname" size="60">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Employee Id <br> <input type="text"
                        placeholder="Employee Id" name="fathername" id="fathername"
                        size="60"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact No. <br> <input type="text" name="paddress"
                        placeholder="Contact Number" id="paddress" size="60"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table width="100" height="100">
                <tr>
                    <th>From Party</th>
                    <th>To Party</th>
                    <th>Docs</th>
                    <th>Created State</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qzs8cd1/1/)

i've changed your html as below

```
<div>

  <table style="width: 50%; float:left">
    <tr>
      <th>Upload a File to BlockChain</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;" bgcolor="#cceeff">
          <tr>
            <td>Name
              <br>
              <input type=text name=textnames placeholder="Employee Name" id="textname">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Employee Id
              <br>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Id" name="fathername" id="fathername">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Contact No.
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="paddress" placeholder="Contact Number" id="paddress">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width: 50%; float:left">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">Transaction Details</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>From Party</th>
      <th>To Party</th>
      <th>Docs</th>
      <th>Created State</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the height="100" and add valign="top" to the td.

```html
<td valign="top">
            <table width="100">
                <tr>
                    <th>From Party</th>
                    <th>To Party</th>
                    <th>Docs</th>
                    <th>Created State</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
```